# Is there an setting for limit video recording in camera2api ?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm creating an android app, and I created a camera recording activity with Camera2api. But I want to limit video length. How can I achieve that?

I already tried  mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(8000);

```
 private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {

        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

//        if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
//            mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
//        }
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.toString());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(8000);
//        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        int rotation =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        switch (mSensorOrientation) {
            case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                break;
            case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                break;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
```

Comment: No, there is no such service from MediaRecorder. But you can set up a timer to stop recording if it's still running. The easiest would be to call `getHandler().postDelayed(runnable, 8000)`, where the **runnable** is a function that **a)** checks `mIsRecording` flag, and **b)** calls `mMediaRecorder.stop()`. If the user stops recording by clicking a button, or switching to another app, set `mIsRecording = false`.